# UnitTest CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: java, junit, java-8, mocking, mockito

I need to test CompletableFuture chain methods, setup looks like this:

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService schedulerService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

@Override
public void interfaceMethod(Param1 p1, Param2 p2) {
    actionSetup(Param1 p1, Param2 p2);
}

// calls firstMethod if gets value calls secondMethod else calls itself till completes
// firstMethod returns Double, secondMethod is void
protected Void actionSetup(Param1 p1, Param2 p2) {
    ScheduledFuture<?> schedule = schedulerService.schedule(() -> firstMethod(Param p1, Param2 p2));
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        Double result = null;
        try {
            result = (Double) schedule.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            actionSetup(Param1 p1, Param2 p2);
        }
        return result;

    }).thenAccept(returnedValue -> secondMethod(Param p1, Param p2))
      .exceptionally(t -> actionSetup(Param1 p1, Param2 p2));

    return null;
}
```

I have not much experience with `CompletableFuture` but I achieved what I planned. I have started to write tests for this method and struggling to test that if `firstMethod` returns not `null` then calls `secondMethod` OR returns null and calls `actionSetup`. Test written so far:

```
@Autowired
TargetService ts;
...
@Test
public void testActionSetup() {
    MockService ms = Mockito.spy(ts);
    ms.actionSetup(Param1 p1, Param2 p2); // forced to return null
    Mockito.verify(spyDeliveryService, Mockito.times(2)); // this is noncompliant

    Mockito.verify(ms, Mockito.times(1)).firstMethod(Param1 p1, Param2 p2);
    // says 'However, there were other interactions with this mock:
    // ts.secondMethod(Param p1, Param p2) was called too
}
```

Using `Void` there so I could use it in `exceptionally`.

Is there a way to `Mockito.verify` multiple calls without at once without `Mockito.times(2)`? Could you provide other ways of checking this? Or there is other ways to test `CompletableFuture` chain method behaviours?

Any help, improvements would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason to split this code into three stages (`supplyAsync`, `thenAccept`, `exceptionally`). Just write a straight-forward code block use `try … catch`, wrap it into a single `runAsync` if you wish. You’ll find that the resulting code is so simple that it doesn’t deserve a unit test at all. Focus on testing that `firstMethod` and `secondMethod` do the right thing.